# Find the element of href that contains javascript

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an apex application i am using selenium when i navigate to the another window,the driver finds the element(button ) but it didn't select it
here it's the html

```
<A role=button id=B152310218175960434 class="uButton " href="javascript:apex.submit('ADDALL');"><SPAN>Add All</SPAN></A>
```

i tried to find it using the id and css but it didnt work.
(N.B)The application runs on IE

Comment: Maybe `$('a[href^="javascript:"]')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it easily using attr here is the example :

```
$('.uButton').attr('href')
```

Comment: could you write in java please

Comment: It is a jquery you need to write it in jquery it will give you the herf value . You will have to use jquery in your html file and you can use <script></script> within that you have to write this code .

Answer (score 0):

You can create the XPath in Java as below:

```
//a[starts-with(@href,"javascript")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should put the code of what you tried and what specific error messages you got to better help us understand what you have tried and why it might not have worked...

You said you tried ID and class but there's no reason with what you have provided that it shouldn't have worked so to get some help, please post more details. Here are some simple things to try that should work... if they don't post the result.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("B152310218175960434")); // by ID
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.uButton")); // by CSS class
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href^='javascript:']")); // Xufox's comment translated into Java
```